# pandas reading excel tables from pandas-exported json

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a small table from excel, which I'd like to read in Pandas. Actually, I have several of the likes, and I'd like to just embed them directly in my script rather than keeping track of separate files.

My file could be a table like this [image]

And now I want to make it embeddable:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("display.width", 1000)

df = pd.read_excel("/your/excel/here/TEST.xlsx")
my_json = df.to_json()

# print of the above json that I want to keep in the script
read_this = {"970":{"0.0":0.0,"0.975301809":0.153,"1.950603618":0.711,"2.925905427":1.269,"3.901207236":1.7775,"4.876509045":1.3125,"5.851810854":0.8475,"6.827112663":0.3825,"7.802414472":0.0,"8.777716281":0.0,"9.75301809":0.0},"1250":{"0.0":0.72,"0.975301809":0.6608,"1.950603618":0.5616,"2.925905427":0.4624,"3.901207236":0.3632,"4.876509045":0.36,"5.851810854":0.36,"6.827112663":0.36,"7.802414472":0.36,"8.777716281":0.36,"9.75301809":0.36},"2000":{"0.0":0.36,"0.975301809":1.18368,"1.950603618":3.50496,"2.925905427":5.383636362,"3.901207236":6.398181817,"4.876509045":9.031304347,"5.851810854":12.91304348,"6.827112663":14.7792,"7.802414472":15.8208,"8.777716281":16.56,"9.75301809":16.56},"3000":{"0.0":2.16,"0.975301809":5.03712,"1.950603618":9.85824,"2.925905427":13.33152,"3.901207236":15.83136,"4.876509045":18.57375,"5.851810854":21.50325,"6.827112663":24.43275,"7.802414472":818.440258,"8.777716281":1625.416258,"9.75301809":2041.92},"4000":{"0.0":8.64,"0.975301809":10.95428571,"1.950603618":16.26857143,"2.925905427":24.38666667,"3.901207236":33.48,"4.876509045":36.50666666,"5.851810854":34.85333333,"6.827112663":387.6812305,"7.802414472":1301.771077,"8.777716281":2215.860923,"9.75301809":2908.8},"5000":{"0.0":7.2,"0.975301809":134.1889811,"1.950603618":492.0670188,"2.925905427":849.9450564,"3.901207236":1207.823094,"4.876509045":1632.171428,"5.851810854":2814.281143,"6.827112663":3996.390856,"7.802414472":5178.500572,"8.777716281":6360.610284,"9.75301809":7542.72},"5500":{"0.0":285.48,"0.975301809":548.6879999,"1.950603618":1290.456,"2.925905427":2032.224,"3.901207236":2773.992,"4.876509045":3515.76,"5.851810854":5088.96,"6.827112663":6662.16,"7.802414472":8235.36,"8.777716281":9808.56,"9.75301809":11381.76},"6000":{"0.0":563.76,"0.975301809":963.1870186,"1.950603618":2088.844981,"2.925905427":3214.502943,"3.901207236":4340.160906,"4.876509045":5399.348572,"5.851810854":7363.638857,"6.827112663":9327.929144,"7.802414472":11292.21943,"8.777716281":13256.50972,"9.75301809":15220.8}}

new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(read_this)

print("original\n", df, "\n")

print("from json\n", new_df)
```

And I get the following

```
original
             970     1250       2000         3000         4000         5000       5500          6000
0.000000  0.0000  0.7200   0.360000     2.160000     8.640000     7.200000    285.480    563.760000
0.975302  0.1530  0.6608   1.183680     5.037120    10.954286   134.188981    548.688    963.187019
1.950604  0.7110  0.5616   3.504960     9.858240    16.268571   492.067019   1290.456   2088.844981
2.925905  1.2690  0.4624   5.383636    13.331520    24.386667   849.945056   2032.224   3214.502943
3.901207  1.7775  0.3632   6.398182    15.831360    33.480000  1207.823094   2773.992   4340.160906
4.876509  1.3125  0.3600   9.031304    18.573750    36.506667  1632.171428   3515.760   5399.348572
5.851811  0.8475  0.3600  12.913043    21.503250    34.853333  2814.281143   5088.960   7363.638857
6.827113  0.3825  0.3600  14.779200    24.432750   387.681231  3996.390856   6662.160   9327.929144
7.802414  0.0000  0.3600  15.820800   818.440258  1301.771077  5178.500572   8235.360  11292.219430
8.777716  0.0000  0.3600  16.560000  1625.416258  2215.860923  6360.610284   9808.560  13256.509720
9.753018  0.0000  0.3600  16.560000  2041.920000  2908.800000  7542.720000  11381.760  15220.800000 

from json
                1250       2000         3000         4000         5000       5500          6000     970
0.0          0.7200   0.360000     2.160000     8.640000     7.200000    285.480    563.760000  0.0000
0.975301809  0.6608   1.183680     5.037120    10.954286   134.188981    548.688    963.187019  0.1530
1.950603618  0.5616   3.504960     9.858240    16.268571   492.067019   1290.456   2088.844981  0.7110
2.925905427  0.4624   5.383636    13.331520    24.386667   849.945056   2032.224   3214.502943  1.2690
3.901207236  0.3632   6.398182    15.831360    33.480000  1207.823094   2773.992   4340.160906  1.7775
4.876509045  0.3600   9.031304    18.573750    36.506667  1632.171428   3515.760   5399.348572  1.3125
5.851810854  0.3600  12.913043    21.503250    34.853333  2814.281143   5088.960   7363.638857  0.8475
6.827112663  0.3600  14.779200    24.432750   387.681231  3996.390856   6662.160   9327.929144  0.3825
7.802414472  0.3600  15.820800   818.440258  1301.771077  5178.500572   8235.360  11292.219430  0.0000
8.777716281  0.3600  16.560000  1625.416258  2215.860923  6360.610284   9808.560  13256.509720  0.0000
9.75301809   0.3600  16.560000  2041.920000  2908.800000  7542.720000  11381.760  15220.800000  0.0000
```

So close, but not really the same. How can I preserve the original structure as an embeddable line of text?

Pastebin of excel file available [here](https://pastebin.com/Ci46inDA)

Comment: As you wish it to be the ouput, I can think of many json structures. Which one will you want?

Comment: Something that preserves my dataframe structure as well as possible, without resorting to pickling external files.

Comment: your answer is as vague as your question, so for me it falls on the off-topic too broad.

Comment: How working `df.to_json(orient='split')` and `df.read_json(orient='split')` ? What means `but for all of them I get various errors` ?

Comment: R has a function called `dput` which is pretty much what I want, but it seems to me that JSON is the closest equivalent that can preserve structure. Or?

Comment: In pandas is used `df.to_pickle()` [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-pickle) or [hdf5](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-hdf5)

Comment: They create new files though. It's like writing `["foo", "bar", "baz"]` to a pickle, instead of just keeping it directly in the script.

Comment: Hmmm, and what about create dictionaries of DataFrames? keys are file names and values are Dataframes?

Comment: Reformatted code to show expected outcome. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Os if use `my_json = df.to_json()` and then `pd.read_json(my_json, orient='split')` it does not work?

Comment: If one of the below solutions solved your problem, please consider accepting (green tick on left), or feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, finally I understand what you want: include the content of your Excel file (i.e. a 2D matrix) directly as a variable in the source code of your script, so that you don't have to read the file anymore. Am I right ?

The native data structure able to store 2D matrices is a **list of lists**. This can be obtained from your Excel file by the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("/your/excel/here/TEST.xlsx")
print("mat =", df.values.tolist())
```

which should print something like:

```
mat = [['', 970, 1250....], [0.00, 0, 0.72...], ...]
```

Then you simply copy the printed lines with your mouse and paste them at the beginning of your code, to create a matrix `mat` that stores your data.

If you need panda DataFrame, simply change the `print` line to:

```
print("df = pd.DataFrame(%s)" % df.values.tolist())
```

and apply the same copy/paste process

Comment: Now I have a new file for every dataframe. I'd like it to be embedded in the script itself.

Comment: I don't understand: when you export to JSON, you also have a new file for every dataframe, so what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, HDF5 is a better option for numeric data. It has type sensitivity, native compression and out-of-memory functionality.

In addition, this format is accessible across languages.

Some example code below, but more information available in [h5py documentation](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/index.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import h5py

# read data
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')

# convert to numpy array
arr = df.values

# extract index and column names
idx = df.index
cols = df.columns

# write to HDF5 file
with h5py.File('out.h5', 'w') as hf:

    hf['/'].attrs['index'] = idx
    hf['/'].attrs['columns'] = cols

    hf.create_dataset('arr', shape=arr.shape, data=arr,
                      compression='gzip', compression_opts=9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I played around a bit, and I found the exact way to be like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

pd.set_option("display.width", 1000)

# Load in the original file (this needs to happen just once)
df = pd.read_excel("/your/excel/here/TEST.xlsx")

# Write this whole table to a single line of dict-formatted JSON for portability
embeddable_json = df.to_json()

# Print it to see the actual output
print(embeddable_json)

# Paste it in here, and wrap it in an OrderedDict to maintain original order
read_this = OrderedDict({"970":{"0.0":0.0,"0.975301809":0.153,"1.950603618":0.711,"2.925905427":1.269,"3.901207236":1.7775,"4.876509045":1.3125,"5.851810854":0.8475,"6.827112663":0.3825,"7.802414472":0.0,"8.777716281":0.0,"9.75301809":0.0},"1250":{"0.0":0.72,"0.975301809":0.6608,"1.950603618":0.5616,"2.925905427":0.4624,"3.901207236":0.3632,"4.876509045":0.36,"5.851810854":0.36,"6.827112663":0.36,"7.802414472":0.36,"8.777716281":0.36,"9.75301809":0.36},"2000":{"0.0":0.36,"0.975301809":1.18368,"1.950603618":3.50496,"2.925905427":5.383636362,"3.901207236":6.398181817,"4.876509045":9.031304347,"5.851810854":12.91304348,"6.827112663":14.7792,"7.802414472":15.8208,"8.777716281":16.56,"9.75301809":16.56},"3000":{"0.0":2.16,"0.975301809":5.03712,"1.950603618":9.85824,"2.925905427":13.33152,"3.901207236":15.83136,"4.876509045":18.57375,"5.851810854":21.50325,"6.827112663":24.43275,"7.802414472":818.440258,"8.777716281":1625.416258,"9.75301809":2041.92},"4000":{"0.0":8.64,"0.975301809":10.95428571,"1.950603618":16.26857143,"2.925905427":24.38666667,"3.901207236":33.48,"4.876509045":36.50666666,"5.851810854":34.85333333,"6.827112663":387.6812305,"7.802414472":1301.771077,"8.777716281":2215.860923,"9.75301809":2908.8},"5000":{"0.0":7.2,"0.975301809":134.1889811,"1.950603618":492.0670188,"2.925905427":849.9450564,"3.901207236":1207.823094,"4.876509045":1632.171428,"5.851810854":2814.281143,"6.827112663":3996.390856,"7.802414472":5178.500572,"8.777716281":6360.610284,"9.75301809":7542.72},"5500":{"0.0":285.48,"0.975301809":548.6879999,"1.950603618":1290.456,"2.925905427":2032.224,"3.901207236":2773.992,"4.876509045":3515.76,"5.851810854":5088.96,"6.827112663":6662.16,"7.802414472":8235.36,"8.777716281":9808.56,"9.75301809":11381.76},"6000":{"0.0":563.76,"0.975301809":963.1870186,"1.950603618":2088.844981,"2.925905427":3214.502943,"3.901207236":4340.160906,"4.876509045":5399.348572,"5.851810854":7363.638857,"6.827112663":9327.929144,"7.802414472":11292.21943,"8.777716281":13256.50972,"9.75301809":15220.8}})

# Read in the above to see if it matches the original file
new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(read_this)

# It does!
print("original\n", df, "\n")
print("from json\n", new_df)
```

So now I can keep small tables around in python script itself, without any external files, applications, pastes, etc.

So next time I can just run this, and the table is already there. No need to keep track of anything else:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

read_this = OrderedDict({"970":{"0.0":0.0,"0.975301809":0.153,"1.950603618":0.711,"2.925905427":1.269,"3.901207236":1.7775,"4.876509045":1.3125,"5.851810854":0.8475,"6.827112663":0.3825,"7.802414472":0.0,"8.777716281":0.0,"9.75301809":0.0},"1250":{"0.0":0.72,"0.975301809":0.6608,"1.950603618":0.5616,"2.925905427":0.4624,"3.901207236":0.3632,"4.876509045":0.36,"5.851810854":0.36,"6.827112663":0.36,"7.802414472":0.36,"8.777716281":0.36,"9.75301809":0.36},"2000":{"0.0":0.36,"0.975301809":1.18368,"1.950603618":3.50496,"2.925905427":5.383636362,"3.901207236":6.398181817,"4.876509045":9.031304347,"5.851810854":12.91304348,"6.827112663":14.7792,"7.802414472":15.8208,"8.777716281":16.56,"9.75301809":16.56},"3000":{"0.0":2.16,"0.975301809":5.03712,"1.950603618":9.85824,"2.925905427":13.33152,"3.901207236":15.83136,"4.876509045":18.57375,"5.851810854":21.50325,"6.827112663":24.43275,"7.802414472":818.440258,"8.777716281":1625.416258,"9.75301809":2041.92},"4000":{"0.0":8.64,"0.975301809":10.95428571,"1.950603618":16.26857143,"2.925905427":24.38666667,"3.901207236":33.48,"4.876509045":36.50666666,"5.851810854":34.85333333,"6.827112663":387.6812305,"7.802414472":1301.771077,"8.777716281":2215.860923,"9.75301809":2908.8},"5000":{"0.0":7.2,"0.975301809":134.1889811,"1.950603618":492.0670188,"2.925905427":849.9450564,"3.901207236":1207.823094,"4.876509045":1632.171428,"5.851810854":2814.281143,"6.827112663":3996.390856,"7.802414472":5178.500572,"8.777716281":6360.610284,"9.75301809":7542.72},"5500":{"0.0":285.48,"0.975301809":548.6879999,"1.950603618":1290.456,"2.925905427":2032.224,"3.901207236":2773.992,"4.876509045":3515.76,"5.851810854":5088.96,"6.827112663":6662.16,"7.802414472":8235.36,"8.777716281":9808.56,"9.75301809":11381.76},"6000":{"0.0":563.76,"0.975301809":963.1870186,"1.950603618":2088.844981,"2.925905427":3214.502943,"3.901207236":4340.160906,"4.876509045":5399.348572,"5.851810854":7363.638857,"6.827112663":9327.929144,"7.802414472":11292.21943,"8.777716281":13256.50972,"9.75301809":15220.8}})
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(read_this)
```

I've only tested for this specific case, so I don't know if there are badly-behaving dataframes.

Hopefully I didn't waste too much of everybody's time.

Comment: Going through a JSON structure followed by an OrderedDict when the data is a simple 2D matrix, appears extremely complicated compared the list-based solution. Remember the Zen of Python: "simple is better than complex" and "complex is better than complicated". But no problem if it fulfils your wishes...

Comment: Perhaps, though this should work for any arbitrary kind of dataframe. It might just be me who's to blame for using a matrix as an example.

Comment: Well, not really because your input format (Excel file) and your output format (Panda DataFrame) are both 2D matrices, so your process will never have to manage complex hierarchical structures (trees or graphs) for which JSON has been developped. But it is always more rewarding to develop a personal solution from A to Z rather than using borrowed code without trying anything else. Grant you for that ;-)